# What state is lost/reset after glUseProgram?

Tags: graphics, opengl-es, glsl, shader

This is related to [Switch shader program in WebGL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9146748/switch-shader-program-in-webgl), but I wanted to re-ask the question now I have a clearer idea of the problem and what I want to ask.

I'm trying to switch between different shader programs, but I can't seem to get things to render correctly when switching shader program in the same render.  I think there is state lost or reset after calling `glUseProgram()`.

What state is lost or reset after that call?  In other words, what do I need to bind again after `glUseProgram()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, that your vertex arrays and vertex attrib arrays have different locations in other programs (such as `this.locATex`), same problems can occur with texture bindings and sampler uniforms for example. You need to query those attrib locations and 'texture unit uniforms', which you need to initialize yourself, for each program individually and bind your arrays and textures accordingly before drawing. Further bindings 'at the other end' can also break, such as fragment data locations. But i suggest, you provide some more code before new problems were invented :-).

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I was looking for more general advice, like do I need to set uniforms again or do they maintain their value?  Do attribute or uniform locations persist their value for one given program?  Does texturing need to be re-enabled? And so on.

Comment: Attrib locations and actual uniform locations and values persist after the program is linked. Uniform buffers can be bound to more programs though. Texturing needs not to be reenabled, because you are not using the fixed function pipeline.

Comment: A texture unit has multiple attachment points, you can bind a 2D and a 3D texture for example and access either of them using an appropriate sampler uniform.

Comment: It is really difficult to give even a rule of thumb, there are too many possibilities for unintended behaviour. Shader and program info logs possibly contain some hints.

Comment: Nothing in the shader or program info logs... arg, I thought there were rules of thumb for things you typically had to re-bind after switching program.  I'm really stuck here, would anyone actually look at it if I posted all 1000 lines of javascript? :P

Comment: Why not, if it can be executed without immense effort...? :)